# Stop an insert with a trigger without propagating error to server side Java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, plsql

There's a Java EE webapp that uses Hibernate,the code of which I don't have access to, so I can't modify or see it. I only have access to the Oracle database.

I have to **create a trigger that avoids an insert from being done** depending on some conditions. This is the relevant code of the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger I have for now:

```
...

if var_some_value = :new.another_value
then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-12345, 'The insert will not be executed');
end if;

...
```

This works fine but the problem is that, this will throw an error that will propagate to the webapp server side code as an `SQLException` or some other type of Exception no matter what.

That's no good because one of the requirements is that the java webapp must not notice that the insert has not been done so the java code should not throw any Exception.

Is there any other way of stopping the row being inserted in a more 'quiet' way?

Maybe I should go for another strategy like an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that deletes the row just inserted if needed. I supose for this I would need to use an autonomous transaction, do the insert and commit it and then delete if it satisfies the conditions. But I'd prefer to use the `BEFORE INSERT` approach if possible.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What server are you talking about? The Oracle database server or some other server the webapp talks to? If the database trigger throws an error it will end up wherever the insert statement came from.

Comment: Edited the question. I mean the java web application should not get the Exception. That's why I ask if there's a way of throwing an Error, or another way of stopping the insert from being done, that does not alert the    java code that the insert hasn't been executed.

Comment: What if the server code does some queries expecting the row to be inserted? Then it will calculate wrong results and/or raise exceptions because of that. Or what if the row being inserted is referenced from another row with a foreign key that the server inserts afterwards. Then it will fail also.

Comment: It's like a historic log table. There would not be such problems in this case because the table is not referenced by any other table, and the app just uses this data to fill a table and show it to the user. But thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the only way to achieve this is to create a view and have the application insert into the view. An instead-of trigger on the view can then handle the insert statements on the view and decide to actually insert into the table or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this would require modifying the application code to make it do the insert in this new view, and I can't modify the code.

Comment: **1.** Rename a `target_table` to `real_target_table`.  **2.** Create view with name `target_table` as `select * from real_target_table`. **3.** Create `instead of` triggers for new view. **4.** Done. Now applications refers to newly created view without modification.

Comment: @ThinkJet I should have said the app uses Hibernate, so if I do this the entity that was mapped to that table now won't be able to find that table, because now it's a view. But this solution would be ideal if there was no JPA/Hibernate involved. Thanks.

Comment: It seems this is the best solution for 'aborting' an insert during a trigger without throwing an error and hence forcing the webapp to handle it. It involves modifying the java code but since this is a very specific requirement of mine I am choosing this answer as correct.